# How to see who is free or occupied during time intervals in sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, overlap

I am wondering how to tackle this problem the easiest way in Google sheets.
So I am wondering how to visualize this in the best way or present it in numbers.

I have some persons that have some calls. What I want to do is somehow to visualize which of those person that where free to take the calls during either 1 hour periods or the whole day.

Example from the table below.
To was occupied from  8:03:54 to 8:06:20 which means that the person could not take any calls during that time. During the 3 first calls only To is available after 8:06:20 which mean that Ma and We were free to talk calls.

So my question is how I can analyze this in the best way to see if people actually could take calls (lets say that all are on place and no one is on break).

If I explained bad, please tell me and I will try to clarify

Here is an example of the table:

| Person | Duration | Starting Time | Ending Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| We | 0:02:21 | 8:58:41 | 9:01:02 |
| Sar | 0:00:56 | 8:59:55 | 9:00:51 |
| G | 0:02:44 | 8:56:13 | 8:58:57 |
| To | 0:02:57 | 8:47:06 | 8:50:03 |
| Ma | 0:06:03 | 8:42:46 | 8:48:49 |
| Sar | 0:01:49 | 8:45:21 | 8:47:10 |
| We | 0:04:41 | 8:35:08 | 8:39:49 |
| We | 0:01:51 | 8:33:13 | 8:35:04 |
| G | 0:02:28 | 8:26:47 | 8:29:15 |
| G | 0:04:21 | 8:21:14 | 8:25:35 |
| To | 0:04:40 | 8:08:26 | 8:13:06 |
| Sar | 0:04:46 | 8:02:23 | 8:07:09 |
| G | 0:04:45 | 8:01:46 | 8:06:31 |
| To | 0:02:26 | 8:03:54 | 8:06:20 |

Comment: `I am wondering how to visualize this in the best way or present it in numbers.` You are asking for an opinion, and that is off-topic for this forum. In any event, the data that you have supplied appears unique to your scenario: it references a single hour of the day, and the smallest element appears to be a milisecond. May I respectfully suggest that you include an example  (_any example_) of how _you_ would visualise your data, OR how you would "report" your data in the context of the outcomes that you are trying to address.